# Create and Insert into nested table

Tags: plsql, nested

Please forgive me, somebody else from my class has asked this question but the answer didn't quite meet my needs. This is coursework so I do not want spoon feeding the answer but a nudge in the right direction would help. I also know that other class friends are using this forum to assist with their work so this answer would be really useful.

This is the question as it has been asked:

> (a) A PL/SQL procedure called INIT_ACTOR_QUOTES with no parameters that:
>
> i. Reads ALL the ACTORIDs from the ACTOR table and INSERTs them into the ACTORID attribute for each row the ACTOR_QUOTES table (the tables have the same cardinality) and at the same time INSERTs the following initial values into the first row only of the QUOTES nested table into each row of the ACTOR_QUOTES table;
>
> `(Movie_Title, Year, Role, Quote)` are set respectively to `(' ',NULL ,' ', ' ')`
>
> Also and at the same time immediately after each INSERT use DELETE to delete ALL the rows from the nested table in each row belonging to each ACTORID in the ACTOR_QUOTES table. (NB: this may seem strange but is necessary as the nested table cannot be populated (because it is atomically null) unless it is initialized, after which this initial data may be deleted).

This is what I have come up with and the response that I get:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INIT_ACTOR_QUOTES
AS
CURSOR actorID_cursor IS
SELECT actorID FROM Actor;
BEGIN 

FOR row IN actorID_cursor LOOP
INSERT INTO actor VALUES (
'00001',

actor_quotes_NT (
quote ('', NULL, ' ', '')
);


DELETE (*) FROM Quotes_NT ('', NULL, ' ', ''); 
END LOOP; 
END INIT_ACTOR_QUOTES ;
```

```
/



LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
8/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/2     PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
16/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
16/9     PL/SQL: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
20/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"
```

I sort of get the principle of what my lecturer is asking but this is giving me a blooming headache. Please help.

Do you need any more information?